# Validar si existe request

Tags: laravel

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy en laravel y lo que pasa es que cuando me meto a la ruta para en este caso guardar registro, osea que el método es por `POST`, cuando escribo en la url la ruta directa en la que guardo los archivos me da este error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

Y pregunto, ¿hay alguna forma de validar si llega `request`? o ¿hay alguna forma de evitar eso para que en este caso me redirija a donde yo le indique?. Desde ya gracias a todos :).

Comment: la ruta POST no puede ser ingresada directamente desde la url. La ruta POST se utiliza desde un formulario o una peticion javascript

Comment: El error que te sale es por que solo GET puede ser accedida desde la url del navegador

Comment: @ClintonTapiaLagar lo se, pero me refiero a que como puedo evitar a que si un usuario hace eso le salga el error que me sale a mi ya sea que lo haga solo porque quiso o por motivos al azar

Comment: En tu archivo .env establecer el valor de APP_DEBUG a false y prueba entrar a la ruta de nuevo

Comment: Eso veria tu usuario en produccion

Comment: No deberías preocuparte por eso, ya que como te dicen acá en estos comentarios, al estar en entorno de **production** con el debug en `false` tu aplicación **Laravel** retorna un **código de estado HTTP** `405`

Comment: @ClintonTapiaLagar  muchas gracias por eso, no sabía que laravel tenía esa función :)